Using MUI Chart options on website warnings appear
I have problem using the chart of MUI.
I get this error on the console:

react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, vertical-July. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

This error happens when I play with the option on the table, I have 4 series, every time I play with the like make it visible or invisible the error happens again and again.
I want to make this warning disappear.
